# MySQL dump not capturing tables located after a view

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-s3

I have a database that has the following structure:

`mysql> show tables;`

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_my_PROD  |
+--------------------+
| table_A            |
| Table_B            |
| table_C            |
| view_A             |
| table_D            |
| table_E            | 
| ...                |
+--------------------+
```

I use a script to make a gzip dump file of my entire database and then I upload that file to Amazon S3. The python code to create the dump file is below:

```
dump_cmd = ['mysqldump ' +
            '--user={mysql_user} '.format(mysql_user=cfg.DB_USER) +
            '--password={db_pw} '.format(db_pw=cfg.DB_PW) +
            '--host={db_host} '.format(db_host=cfg.DB_HOST) +
            '{db_name} '.format(db_name=cfg.DB_NAME) +
            '| ' +
            'gzip ' +
            '> ' +
            '{filepath}'.format(filepath=self.filename)]

dc = subprocess.Popen(dump_cmd, shell=True)
dc.wait()
```

This creates the zip file. Next, I upload it to Amazon S3 using python's boto library.

When I go to restore a database from that zip file, I only get tables A, B and C restored. Tables D and E are nowhere to be found.

*Tables D and E are after the view*

Is there something about that view that is causing problems? I do not know if the tables are getting dumped to the file because I do not know how to look into that file (table_B has 8 million rows and any attempt to inspect the file crashes everything)

I am using Mariadb version

```
+-------------------------+------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value            |
+-------------------------+------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.23-72.1      |
| protocol_version        | 10               |
| slave_type_conversions  |                  |
| version                 | 10.0.19-MariaDB  |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server   |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64           |
| version_compile_os      | Linux            |
| version_malloc_library  | bundled jemalloc |
+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: You could use `zgrep CREATE filename` to see whether it's creating the tables.

Comment: @Barmar it looks like the tables after the view are not being created

Comment: Is it creating the views themselves? If not, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63320/problem-with-mysqldump-and-view. This question should probably be migrated to dba.SE.

Comment: @Barmar using `zgrep`, I saw the tables were not being created. the dump procedure was erroring with: `Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `view_A`': View 'my_PROD.view_A' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)` I deleted the view and I seem to be ok now.

Comment: You just need to give yourself appropriate grants to dump the view. Did you read the question I linked to above?

Comment: Isn't deleting the view going to break your application? Or is it an obsolete view that tries to use tables/columns that no longer exist?

Comment: @Barmar I did, thank you. I think it was that the view was old and pointed to some obsolete / missing tables, so that's where it was failing. The backup routine is hidden under many layers of abstraction, so I was missing some important stdout

Comment: Actually, you were missing STDERR... which this code is effecrively discarding.  `dc.wait()` also probably returns nonzero on error, and that's also not being evaluated.